# MKMapview showing current location wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dictionary, mkmapview

I am using MKMapView and it is showing my current location. in india it is showing well and exact what in google map but in US current location is showing wrong.

i am using

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an MKMapView you can use its delegate method mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:

You need to set showsUserLocation property of your map view to YES.
Then the map view uses CoreLocation framework to determine current location.

It tracks userLocation by itself whenever it receives location updates and updates it periodically.